# How to make a cookie for a link to a php but different output

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cookies, localhost

Im using mysql database. I want to make a link that link to a php page.

```
 <?php   
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("scratchdisk",$connection);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM note";   
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table>";   
echo "<tr><td>#</td><td>Title</td><td>Action</td></tr>";  

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['#']."</td><td>".$row['Title']."</td><td><a href='view.php' id='view'>View</a></td></tr>";   } 
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

I want to display the next page base on my `$row['#']` but the same view.php file.

Comment: I can't fix the formatting. something is really screwed up.

Comment: Change `href='view.php'` so it has an identifier. `href='view.php?id=" . $row['#'] . "'` then on your next page use `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<?php   
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("scratchdisk",$connection);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM note";   
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table>";   
echo "<tr><td>#</td><td>Title</td><td>Action</td></tr>";  

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['#']."</td><td>".$row['Title']."</td><td><a href='view.php?id=" . $row['#'] . "' id='view'>View</a></td></tr>";   } 
 echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

In **view.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])){
  //Write logic here
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```